# Querying Firebase data with AngularFire2 in Ionic 2

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 with ionic 2 and storing the data in webSqlStorage.

When I complete the the first GET it saves it to storage. What I want to do is if the user has a connection then check the data from Firebase, if it has not changed, then get the local data, else get the updated data.

Currently, I have a simple check to see if there the storage is not null which then gets the local data, but this will not work for production.

```
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: 'Getting Programs...'
});

loader.present().then(() => {

  this.storage.get('programs').then((data) => {

    if (data != null) {
      loader.setContent("Getting Local Data...");
      this.programs = data;

    } else {
      this.yApi.getPrograms().then(data => {
        this.programs = data;
        this.storage.set('programs', data);
      },err => {
        // Probaly offline with no local data
        console.log("Err is to human");
      });
    }

  }).then(() => {
    loader.dismiss();
  });

});
```

Just wondering if there is a way to write something like

```
if (data != null || this.af.checkUpdated('/programs')) { ...
```

or something.

Answer (score 1):

I used an additional database value like program_version in my projects. If firebase program_version is greater than the local storage, than update. On every program update your program_version will be increased or set a timestamp.

Comment: Very interesting idea .. will try that